# How to display errors from associated model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I have `article` and `comment` model.

I want to write this:

```
= form_for ([@article, @article.comments.build]) do |f|
  - if @article.comments.errors.any?
    %h4 Errors
    %ul
      - @article.comments.errors.full_message do |message|
        %li= message
```

But I get error:

> undefined method `errors' for
>   Comment::ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy:0x9a4a020

`Article` has many comments and `comment` belongs to article.

I want to display validation error for my comment.

EDIT:
My `comment` model:

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :article
  validates :author, presence: true, length: { minimum: 3 }
  validates :body, presence: true, length: { minimum: 5 }
end
```

Comment: `@article.comments.first.` ?

Comment: Now there is no error. But the validation errors aren't displayed when should be (in model I have presence validation etc.).

Comment: show the validation you wrote inside the model

Answer (score 1):

You can't call errors on a collection like `@article.comments`.

In your controller, create an instance variable for comment:

```
def new
  @comment = @article.comments.build
end

def create
  @comment = @article.comments.build
  respond_to do |format|
  if @comment.save
    # handle save
  else
     format.html { render :new }
     format.json { render json: @comment.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```

Then update your form:

```
= form_for ([@article, @comment]) do |f|
  - if @comment.errors.any?
    %h4 Errors
    %ul
      - @comment.errors.full_message do |message|
        %li= message
```